# ImportError en el jupyter notebook despite installing the library called

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

I tried to import a library but it does not seem to be added to jupyter notebook

```
import sys

print("sys.executable:\n",sys.executable)
print("sys.path:\n",sys.path)

from textblob import TextBlob
```

And it gives me:

> ```
>     sys.executable:
>      /usr/bin/python3
>     sys.path:
>      ['', '/usr/lib/python35.zip', '/usr/lib/python3.5', '/usr/lib/python3.5/plat-x86_64-linux-gnu', 
> '/usr/lib/python3.5/lib-dynload', '/home/mike/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages',
> '/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages',
> '/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages',
> '/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/IPython/extensions',
> '/home/mike/.ipython']
>
>     ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
>     ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
>     <ipython-input-2-ab115a97c7b9> in <module>()
>          10 print("sys.path:\n",sys.path)
>          11 
>     ---> 12 from textblob import TextBlob
>          13 import nltk
>          14 from scipy import spatial
>
>     ImportError: No module named 'textblob'
> ```

To solve the problem I tried

```
python -m pip install ipykernel
python -m  ipykernel install
```

But it does not wor even if it works well with the Python interpreter:

```
(mybot_env) mike@mike-thinks:~/Programming/mybot$ python Python 3.5.2 (default, Nov 23 2017, 16:37:01)  [GCC 5.4.0 20160609] on linux Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import textblob 
/usr/lib/python3.5/importlib/_bootstrap.py:222: RuntimeWarning: numpy.dtype size changed, may indicate binary incompatibility. Expected 96, got 88   return f(*args, **kwds) 
/usr/lib/python3.5/importlib/_bootstrap.py:222: RuntimeWarning: numpy.dtype size changed, may indicate binary incompatibility. Expected 96, got 88   return f(*args, **kwds) 
/usr/lib/python3.5/importlib/_bootstrap.py:222: RuntimeWarning: numpy.dtype size changed, may indicate binary incompatibility. Expected 96, got 88   return f(*args, **kwds)
>>>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It may be installing with python executable your jupyter is not using. you can directly install in jupyter shell by allowing python executable your jupyter is using:

```
import sys
!{sys.executable} -m pip install textblob
```